# The machine is laggy and the SMC reset is not working

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra

Recently my 2015 MacBook Pro started to lag a lot, especially the graphics. The animations are really slow and breaking up sometimes. Someone suggested an NVRAM reset followed by an SMC reset will fix it.

The NVRAM is working. But the SMC reset is not. I tried to hold  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>    <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   + the power button up to 30 seconds. Still, it's not resetting (The color of the mag safe connector is not changing.). Any idea what's happening?

A screenshot of the activity monitor:

[image]

Comment: You are doing the SMC reset wrong Check this official https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201295 document from Apple on how to perform a SMC reset and also attach a screenshot of activity monitor with your question and check which application or process is taking up the most CPU percentage!

Comment: Already followed the guide many times. No help.

Comment: Attach a screenshot of the processes in Activity monitor

Comment: Just uploaded :-)

Comment: Can you please update your answer with details from an EtreCheck scan? This will check to see what's installed (particularly checking for adware and malware) as wells anything else that may be affecting performance. Check out EtreCheck here: https://etrecheck.com

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to boot into single-user mode ( boot while holding down the command and the S buttons untill you see a black screen ) and then run " fsck -fy " command?

This will run some diagnostics and make any changes needed. When it is finished it will say  drive appears to be ok OR changes were made.

You then type " reboot " ( without quotation marks ) and it will reboot.

[Troubleshoot Your Mac With These Hidden Startup Options](https://www.howtogeek.com/189104/troubleshoot-your-mac-with-these-hidden-startup-options/)

[Use safe mode to isolate issues with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262)